# Behaviour of null in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, concatenation

This probably looks duplicate of other questions on SO. But, I was wondering the way Java treat `null`.

Eg:

```
public class Work {
    String x = null;
    String y;
    Integer z;

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Work w = new Work();
        w.x = w.x + w.y; // work Line 1
        w.x = w.x + w.y + w.z; // work Line 2
        w.z = w.z + w.z; // NullPointerException Line 3
        System.out.println(w.x.charAt(4));
    }
}
```

Commenting `Line 3` prints `n` whereas uncommenting throws `NullPointerException`. If I'm not wrong for `Line 1` and `Line 2`, it being implicitly type cast to `String`. But, what happen to `Line 3` ?

Comment: *"But, what happen to Line 3 ? "* Unboxing of `Integer` to `int`.

Comment: what about `Line 2` ? Trying to concatenate `Integer` and `String`

Comment: You already know it, so what is your question?

Comment: It was my assumption that, it is being type cast to `String`. But, as you mentioned about `Integer` that it was unboxed to `int`. Then, in that case, It should display `nullnull0`. right ? Because int default value is `0`.

Comment: Yes, the default of `int` is `0`, but you have no `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` has a lot of special allowances in Java, for better or for worse. The specification dictates that `null` gets converted to the string `"null"` when converted to a string, e.g. by string concatenation (which implicitly calls `toString()` on other operands). So adding `null` to a string works by virtue of the language spec saying so.

Based on this your first two lines will result in

```
w.x = "null" + "null";
w.x = "nullnull" + "null" + "null";
```

In line 3 you get a different phenomenon, in this case auto-boxing and -unboxing. To ease the disconnect between primitive types and their respective wrapper classes you can apply arithmetic operators to wrapper classes, which prompt their values to be unboxed, operated on, and the result being boxed again. And this is where the `NullReferenceException` happens, because `w.z` is still `null` and thus cannot be unboxed. In essence:

```
w.z = w.z + w.z
```

is turned by the compiler into:

```
w.z = Integer.valueOf(w.z.intValue() + w.z.intValue());
```

and the call to `intValue()` is what fails because `w.z` is `null` here.

Prior to Java 5 this is what you had to write yourself if you wanted to have calculations on `Integer` objects.

Answer (score 5):

Unboxing happens. Integer doesn't have + operator. It has to be unboxed to int (primitive).

Answer (score 0):

In java, reference  default value is `null`. When you declared `z` but not initialized, then it will take default value as `null` since `z` is a reference variable. Therefore you got `NullPointerException`.

There are 2 ways that you can avoid `NullPointerException`.

1. Initialize z.

   ```
   public class Work {
       String x = null;
       String y;
       Integer z = 0;   

       public static void main(String arg[]) {
           Work w = new Work();
           w.x = w.x + w.y; // work Line 1
           w.x = w.x + w.y + w.z; // work Line 2
           w.z = w.z + w.z; // work Line 3 
           System.out.println(w.x.charAt(4));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use valueOf(int i) when you re assign.

   `w.z = (null == w.z) ? 0 : Integer.valueOf(w.z.intValue() + w.z.intValue());`